# Eclipse ADT - Not Installing Plugin - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu, adt

I have an ADT installed. I am unable to add plugins from **Help** -> **Install Software** as it says pending forever.TrepN shows fetching children but it never crosses **2%**

I know this is due to the Proxy Server of our institute and has changed the settings in **Window** --> **Preferences** -> **Network Connection** and restarted it but there is no change.

I am using *Ubuntu* 14.04. I have searched the net extensively and everybody tell to update the network settings which I have done. But still this is not working. Even the SDK manager is not updating because of this. I am sure this is due to proxy but the usual workaround is not working.
Could anybody please solve this problem
[image: Manual]
[image: Plugin][image: Direct]![image: Native]